# How to make a ndarray class object with function to change itself?

Tags: python, class

I would like to have a class like this

```
class Test(np.ndarray):

    def shift_up(self):
        arr = np.copy(self)
        n = len(self)
        for i in range(1,n)[::-1]:
            arr[i] = arr[i-1]
        arr[0] = np.nan
        self.__init__(arr)

    def truncate(self,index):
        arr = np.copy(self)
        arr_slice = np.copy(arr[:index+1])
        self.__init__(arr_slice) 

array = Test(np.array([1,2,3,4,5]))
array.truncate(5)
```

I know I can just do it with the numpy functions. But I want it to be like this just to make it more legible. But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
class Test(np.ndarray):
  def __init__(self,npArray):
    self.__npArr__ = npArray.copy()
  def shift_up(self):
    tempArr = list(self.__npArr__)
    if len(tempArr) <1:
        pass #Make sure to check the boundaries
    for i in range(len(tempArr)-1,0,-1):
      tempArr[i] = tempArr[i-1]
    tempArr[0] = np.nan
    self.__npArr__ = tempArr
  def truncate(self,index):
    if index > len(self.__npArr__):
      pass #Make sure you check the boundaries first
    self.__npArr__ = self.__npArr__[:index]
  def __str__(self): #This is called when you're trying to print the object
    return str(self.__npArr__)
    
array = Test( np.array([1,2,3,4,5]))
print(array)
array.truncate(3)
print(array)
array.shift_up()
print(array)
```

It's better to use Mohammad's approach
This truncate method should work:

```
def truncate(self,index):
        if index > len(self):
          pass #Make sure you check the boundaries first
        obj = self[:index]
        return obj
```

so that when you call it you can

```
array = array.truncate(3)
```

Comment: This works when printing. But I can't access the numpy array like array[0]. I would have to do array.__npArr__[0], which kind of defeats the purpose of trying to make it more legible.

Comment: Hi! I added truncate method that would work in Mohammed's approach.

Comment: if I had to do array = array.truncate(3)
array = array[:3] would be way more legible.

Why I wanted a class is because I could go like,
array.shift_up() which is very short and without = sign.
If I had to use = sign, just using the statement directly would be easier to understand.

I think we can confidently say it is actually impossible to do what I want to do for numpy arrays, appreciate the effort though.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question about shifting up the array, you should know that **the main problem is that you modify a copy of the array, not the array itself**. I write an example to shift up elements in the array.

```
def shift_up(self):
    # define a variable to access self
    arr = self

    # keep last element
    last_element = arr[-1]

    # shift other elements
    n = len(self)
    for i in range(1,n)[::-1]:
        arr[i] = arr[i-1]
      
    # put last value to first elemetn to rotate
    arr[0] = last_element
```

you also override **new** to easily instantiate Test objects. Full code is like this:

```
import numpy as np

class Test(np.ndarray): 

    # this helps to create instace of Test
    def __new__(cls, a):
        obj = np.asarray(a).view(cls)
        return obj


    def shift_up(self):
        # define a variable to access self
        arr = self

        # keep last element
        last_element = arr[-1]

        # shift other elements
        n = len(self)
        for i in range(1,n)[::-1]:
            arr[i] = arr[i-1]
          
        # put last value to first elemetn to rotate
        arr[0] = last_element


array = Test(np.array([1,2,3,4,5]))
array.shift_up()
print(array)
```

Comment: I know you can directly modify it within the method. But the thing is truncating doesn't work that way.